# Devise - setting default values for new users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using Devise for user sign ups in my Rails app.  The Users table has a column called `admin`, which is boolean.  I would like to set it so that the value of `admin` automatically defaults to `false` for every new user that signs up.  I've tried a number of different approaches, but nothing seems to work.

I'm looking for something like this to happen:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :first_name
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :last_name
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :phone
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << {:admin => false}
  end
end
```

Although this, as I said, doesn't work.  But something like that.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the default value of an attribute in the model.  In the migration:

```
add_column :admin, :boolean, :default => false
```

You can then ensure that the value is set on save:

```
before_save :default_admin
def default_admin
   self.admin ||= false
end
```

Answer (score 3):

A more correct answer is:

```
# models/user.rb
before_create :default_admin
def default_admin
   self.admin ||= false
end
```

because is only on `create` and no in `uptade` like `before_save`

Comment: This is wrong. If a user is created manually in the code as in `u = User.new` and  `user.save`, it will set admin = false when devise was not involved in the creation of the user.

Comment: @gitb neither accepted answer and this was to work only with devise. both answer user rails callback that apply to all model create/update. If you want a only devise method I do not know.